# Send emails with attachments in salesforce via sendgrid

Tags: salesforce, sendgrid

I am trying to generate a pdf and attach to an email and send it.
I am using salesforce and sendgrid.
I am able to send emails but the problem is when I try to attach the pdf, the email is with the attachment, but this is broken, the file is not empty, but the pdf says is broken (I think is a problem of conversion)
here is the code

```
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    PageReference pdf = Page.include_attachment;
  pdf.getParameters().put('id', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    blob fileBody = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
    efa.setBody(fileBody);
    efa.setFileName('test.pdf');
    efa.setContentType('application/pdf;charset=UTF-8;');
    send('xxxxx@xxxx.com','Test','Body Test', fileBody);
```

I tryied using

```
pdf.getContentAsPDF();
```

and

```
pdf.getContent();
```

but the result is the same.

Send method

```
public static void send(String emailRecipient, String emailSubject, String emailBody, Blob att){
    Boolean success=true;

    //construct the body of the request
    String requestBody='';
    requestBody += 'to='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(emailRecipient,'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&from='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(user.Email,'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&fromname='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(user.Name,'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&subject='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(emailSubject,'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&text='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(emailBody.trim(),'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&html='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(emailBody.trim(),'UTF-8');
    requestBody += '&api_user=xxxxx';
    requestBody += '&api_key=xxxxx';
    requestBody += '&files[attachment.pdf]=@'+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att);

    //construct request
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(requestBody);
    try{
        //send request
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        //check response
        String status = res.getStatus();
        if(status.toUpperCase()=='OK'){
            success=true;
        }
        else{
            success=false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        success=false;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You might want to contact [Scott Motte](https://twitter.com/scottmotte). He is creating a library for working with SendGrid from Salesforce.
What does the body of your send method look like?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @Daniel , I posted the send method.

Comment: Like [Daniel Ballinger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/54026/daniel-ballinger) said I'm working on a library right now. Daniel's been helping. I don't have the answer for this right now but am working on this today.

Comment: @scottmotte
can you please review this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78072441/retrieve-sendgrid-email-templates-to-salesforce-code-via-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a library/devtoolkit to do this for you. At the time of this writing it is in beta, but it is working. Disclaimer: I work at SendGrid and have just recently developed the library.

[sendgrid-apex](https://github.com/scottmotte/sendgrid-apex)

You can rewrite your code to:

```
...
Blob att = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
public static void send(String emailRecipient, String emailSubject, String emailBody, Blob att){

  SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'password');

  SendGrid.email email = new SendGrid.Email();
  email.addTo(emailRecipient);
  email.setFrom(user.Email);
  email.setFromName(user.Name);
  email.setSubject(emailSubject);
  email.setText(emailBody.trim());
  email.setHtml(emailBody.trim());
  email.addAttachmentStream("attachment.pdf", att);

  String response = sendgrid.send(email);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! I am trying to implement your solution, is working when I attach a txt, but not when I try to generate in Salesforce a pdf, and then attach it (the error I get is BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string), which makes sense, but maybe there is a way to solve this, I will keep trying to fixit. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, that might be a bug (in my understanding of how to handle blobs). The code causing that error is [here](https://github.com/scottmotte/sendgrid-apex/blob/master/src/classes/SendGrid.cls#L143). It's trying to convert it toString but not coming back as UTF-8. I've posted it as an issue [here](https://github.com/scottmotte/sendgrid-apex/issues/1) and will work on fixing it.

Comment: @scottmotte , is there any solution available for this problem?