# Retrieve Sendgrid Email templates to Salesforce code via API

Tags: salesforce, sendgrid, email-templates, sendgrid-templates

I am using salesforce app to send emails.
I want to retrieve Dynamic email templated from Sendgrid to my salesforce app using API and then user will select one of the retrieved template to send email.
Instead of providing hardcoded template id in the request, can i get the email templates dynamically from sendgrid? and how i can get them in apex or js by making API call?

I didnt find the way in Apex or Js to make API call to sendgrid.
Also i found that template id is mentioned hardcoded in the request. But i want to retrieve them dynamically.